# Is there a game similar to Bloodborne the Card Game with a lighter theme?

Tags: recommendations

Yesterday I played Bloodborne the Card Game and loved it! The theme, however, is a little dark for my family (getting killed several times, collecting "blood echoes" which are blood colored chips, and an overall lack of bright colors). What games have similar mechanics and game length, but with a "lighter" theme?

"Bloodborne the Card Game" is a cooperative/competitive card game where you fight a series of monsters and collect victory points that can be lost when you die if you haven't cashed them. You start with five cards and gain only a few more cards before it's over that upgrade your character. It lasts 30-45 minutes, and is for 3-6 players.

Answer (score 1):

Cutthroat Caverns might scratch that same itch. Card based combat mixed with some take that.

Basically you fight monsters via cooperation but the player that deals the final blow gets the loot, so that is the competitive part.

Here is the BGG page:
https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/28259/cutthroat-caverns

Answer (score 1):

Dungeon Raiders seems like much lighter game with similar concepts.
https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/80771/dungeon-raiders